# custom parse with logstash and elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to logstash !
I configured and everything is working fine - so far.
My log files comes as:

```
2014-04-27 16:24:43 DEBUG b45e66 T+561   10.31.166.155   /v1/XXX<!session> XXX requested for category_ids: only_pro: XXX_ids:14525
```

If i use the following conf file:

```
input { file { path => "/logs/*_log" }} output { elasticsearch { host => localhost } }
```

It will place the following in the ES:

```
{
  _index: "logstash-2014.04.28",
  _type: "logs",
  _id: "WIoUbIvCQOqnz4tMZzMohg",
  _score: 1,
  _source: {
    message: "2014-04-27 16:24:43 DEBUG b45e66 T+561 10.31.166.155 This is my log !",
    @version: "1",
    @timestamp: "2014-04-28T14:25:52.165Z",
    host: "MYCOMPUTER",
    path: "\logs\xxx_app.log"
   }
  }
```

How do i take the string in my log so the entire text wont be at _source.message ?
e.g: I wish i could parse it to something like:

```
 {
  _index: "logstash-2014.04.28",
  _type: "logs",
  _id: "WIoUbIvCQOqnz4tMZzMohg",
  _score: 1,
  _source: {
    logLevel: "DEBUG",
    messageId: "b45e66",
    sendFrom: "10.31.166.155",
    logTimestamp: "2014-04-27 16:24:43",
    message: "This is my log !",
    @version: "1",
    @timestamp: "2014-04-28T14:25:52.165Z",
    host: "MYCOMPUTER",
    path: "\logs\xxx_app.log"
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse it through a filter, e.g. the [grok filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/filters/grok). This can be quite a bit tricky, so be patient and try, try, try. And have a look at the predefined [patterns](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/v1.4.0/patterns/grok-patterns), too.

A start for your message would be

`%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:logLevel} %{WORD:messageId} %{GREEDYDATA:someString} %{IP}`

The [grokdebugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com) is an extremely helpful tool for your assistance.

When done, your config should look like

```
input {
   stdin {}
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:logLevel} %{WORD:messageId} %{GREEDYDATA:someString} %{IP}" }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```